Transposing French horn parts (BC + TC) in lilypond
I'm looking at a German 1876 horn part that's written "in Es" like this:

If I were to transpose that into concert-pitch, I think:

horn bass clef transposes up (c sounds like ees), and
horn treble clef transposes down (c'' sounds like ees').


I'd like to write the part in LilyPond only once in Es, and produce a midi, an Es part, and a concert-pitch part.  Writing the notes is easy:
hornMusic = {
  \key c \major
  \time 6/8
  \clef bass     c,4.~(  4  g,8     |  c4.~   4  e8  |
  \clef treble   g'4.~   4  c''8    |  e''2.)        |
}

But how do I create a midi output and a concert-pitch part out of this?
The following produces a correct part in Es, but a midi where the bass-clef measures sound an octave low.  If I use \transposition ees', then the treble clef measures sound an octave high.  Likewise, when making a concert-pitch part, \transpose c ees, results in bass clef being written an octave too low.
% Part in Es + midi
\score{
  \new Staff \with { midiInstrument = "french horn" }{
    \transposition ees   % Bass clef sounds an octave low in midi
    \hornMusic  
  }
  \midi{}
  \layout{}
}

% Part in concert pitch
\score{
  \new Staff {
    \transpose c ees    % Treble clef is written an octave too high
    \hornMusic 
  }
}


I wish that my example was in F, to follow modern notation, but it should be the same concept/problem/solution.

Edit:  Working with custom clefs:
As Michael Seifert hints, the answer might be a custom clef.  We need to write the hornMusic in that section up one octave, but that's fine.
clefBassHorn = {
  \set Staff.clefGlyph = "clefs.F"
  \set Staff.clefPosition = 2
  \set Staff.middleCPosition = -1
}

or
clefBassHorn = {
  \override Staff.ClefModifier.stencil = ##f
  \clef "bass^8"
}

Then using it with:
hornMusic = {
  \key c \major
  \time 6/8
  \clefBassHorn   c4.~(  4  g8      |  c'4.~  4  e'8 |
  \clef treble   g'4.~   4  c''8    |  e''2.)        |
}

\score{
  \new Staff \with { midiInstrument = "french horn" }{
    \transposition ees \hornMusic
  }
  \midi{}
  \layout{}
}

\score{
  \new Staff {
    \transpose c ees { \hornMusic }
  }
}

This works great for the midi output, and the transposed (Es) part.  But, as phoong suggested, it breaks when moving it to concert-pitch where I want a normal clef, and it doesn't make sense when I try to re-use that section in another part (like trombone).
I'm thinking that I need some sort of conditional, that I can define when I create my Staff.
#(define-music-function weirdHornClef (useHornClef) (boolean?)
#{
  \if #useHornClef
    clefBassHorn = { \clef "bass^8" }
  \unless #useHornClef
    clefBassHorn = { \clef bass }
#}

\new Staff \with { weirdHornClef true }{ ... }

But I'm not sure of the syntax to get that working.

I don't have time to work up an answer, but I expect that the clarinet example at the bottom of the documentation page should point the way.

Thanks for the response, but the problem isn't how to transpose.  The problem is how to use a different transposition for bass clef vs treble clef (which is convention for French horn).

The clarinet example shows how to specify a changing transposition within the part rather than as a property of the staff.  You ought to be able to change the transposition at the same point as the clef change.

Oh, you're suggesting that I use \transposition and \transpose inside of \hornMusic near the \clef statements.  But then I'd need to wrap that in some sort of conditional flag that I would need to enable/disable from the staff if I want to re-use the music for both parts.  I'm still not quite sure how to do that.

But the horn part has a written leap of a 12th that should sound as a fifth.  If that isn't handled somehow in the hornMusic object itself, you'll need to apply some sort of special handling to it to reuse it for a different instrument.  That is, even if there were a HornStaff object that handled the horn transpositions correctly, you'd have a problem when you want to render hornMusic for a trombone, which wants the whole thing in concert pitch (and probably the high notes in tenor clef).

You have a perfect understanding of the problem!  I'm wrestling with some define-music-function right now to try and brew something where I can use \hornBassClef around those notes, and define whether it should be written/sound an octave higher from the staff or if it should even change clef at all.

Would transposing the entire part down and using \clef "bass_8" for the bass clef sections be a valid workaround?  You might even be able to suppress the engraver for the number so that the musician wouldn't notice the difference.

(To be clear, this would involve writing something like \clef "bass_8"     c4.~(  4  g8     |  c'4.~   4  e'8  | for the first two measures and leaving the second measure as is.)

Yes!  I think we're converging on a solution.  I just created clefBassHorn = { \set Staff.clef... } to make a custom bass clef with Staff.middleCPosition = -1.  I need to enter the notes up, an octave (which is fine), but the Es part looks good, and the midi looks good.  Now I just need a way to turn that into a standard bass clef when I generate the concert-pitch part.

I would suggest notating this using \treble_8 and omit the clef modifier. This most accurately encodes what is actually happening while being easily switchable with a simple styleset to show the modifier to avoid confusion.

As you mention, in this old notation the transposition changes depending on which clef you are in:  In bass clef the music sounds up (a minor 3rd), but in treble clef it sound down (a major 6th).
Thinking about it another way, the transposition is consistently down, but the bass clef is really an octave bass clef that doesn’t showing little 8 above.  (You can make either of these ways of thinking work, but this second way makes the coding easier.)

You want 3 different outputs:

The Part in Es (transposed in old notation)
The MIDI file
The Part in Concert Pitch

1. The Part in Es
To get the transposed part, write the bass notes in an octave bass clef (\clef "bass^8") (an octave higher than they look), and turn off the clef modifier stencil, i.e.
        \override Staff.ClefModifier.stencil = ##f
        \clef "bass^8"
            c4.~( 4 g8 |
            c'4.~ 4 e'8 |

Write the treble clef notes in as they look, i.e.
        \clef "treble"
            g'4.~ 4 c''8 |
            e''2.) |

This way both treble and bass have the same transposition.
To change to new notation you can simply replace \clef "bass^8" with \clef "bass".
2. The MIDI file
To get the MIDI file to sound right you’ll just need to add \transposition es.
3. The Part in Concert Pitch
To get the concert pitch output to look right, you can use \transpose c' es, but the bass will still appear in the octave clef (even though the little 8 isn’t printed).  You can fix this by using a tag.
When in bass, change the clef to a regular bass clef (\clef "bass") but wrap this in a concert-pitch tag.  Remove this tag (with \removeWithTag #'concert-pitch) from the score block that generates the part in Es and the MIDI.
We can tidy up the code by storing the horn bass clef setup in a macro.
\version "2.24.1"

hornBassClef = {
    \override Staff.ClefModifier.stencil = ##f
    \clef "bass^8"
    \tag #'concert-pitch {
        \clef "bass"
    }
}

hornMusic = {
    \new Staff {
        \set Staff.midiInstrument = "french horn"
        \key c \major
        \time 6/8
        \transposition es
        
        \hornBassClef
            c4.~( 4 g8 |
            c'4.~ 4 e'8 |
        
        \clef "treble"
            g'4.~ 4 c''8 |
            e''2.) |
    }
}

% Part in Es + midi
\score {
    \removeWithTag #'concert-pitch
    
    \hornMusic
    
    \midi {}
    \layout {}
}

% Part in concert pitch
\score {
    \transpose c' es {
        \hornMusic
    }
}


This works really well!!  Unrelated questin, you moved the \new Staff definition into hornMusic.  Why is that?  I usually keep the music and the staves separate so I can \partCombine when I need to produce a condensed score.  I understand if it's just to reduce the number of lines to make your answer more readable.

@Stewart Sometimes I do that too (especially with horn music).  I don’t think it makes much difference in this example though; maybe it’s a little neater with one call to \new Staff rather than two.
